# Separate json key : value by comma, but with not closed quotes inside value quotes

Tags: regex

For example I have this json:

```
{"a":"some value", "b":"some value", "c": "some ,\" value"}
```

I need to get:

`"a":"some value" and "b":"some value" and "c": "some ," value"`

I have ended with this regex `(,)(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)`, but this doesn't work with third key value pair.

Comment: Just to clarify, that example is invalid JSON; are you sure this is the format you have? If it was valid JSON, it would be much easier to parse it rather than writing your own regex.

Comment: updated question, I need to exactly separate json key value by comma, not just parse it

Comment: If you have JSON then use a JSON parser. There's really no need to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must do this with regex then you can try:

```
(".*?(?<!\\)")\s*:\s*(".*?(?<!\\)")
```

- `(".*?` - start a capture group and match an opening double-quote and lazily match zero or more of any char
- `(?<!\\)` - make sure that a `\` does not precede the closing double-quote
- `")` - find a closing double-quote and close the capture group
- `\s*:\s*` - match a colon `:` surrounded by optional whitespace
- `(".*?(?<!\\)")` - see bullet points 1 through 3

https://regex101.com/r/25qa84/1

Comment: This will not work when not closed quote will be inside value quotes

Comment: @DarkenAki What are you talking about? Your example mentions nothing of this and if this is happening then you have invalid JSON to start with.

Comment: @DarkenAki If the JSON is valid, then quotes inside the quoted string will always be preceded by a backslash, as in your example in the question which has `"some ,\" value"`. The `(?<!\\)"` in the regex ignores these by looking for "any quote mark not preceded by a backslash"